# Why the data type of tags column in planet_osm_ways table is not in JSON format?

Tags: json, postgresql, openstreetmap

I have been working on the OSM data, that I imported to my postgresql database using [osm2pgsql](http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm2pgsql/). This generated few tables in my postgre database, which contains a table **planet_osm_ways**. The planet osm can be studied [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Worldwide_extract_sources). The planet_osm_ways has the following sample of data:
[image]

**QUESTION:**
The tags column in the above table is not in JSON format. Would it not be useful to have this data in JSON format?

I believe it will be very useful in accessing the tags, such as if the data is in JSON format, content of "name" key can be accessed very easily. In current state, there is no solution other than to parse all of the tags in each instance of tags column.

Looking forward for interesting suggestions and to know if there is any particular reason for not keeping the tags data in JSON format. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The data is in JSON format -- do you mean to ask why it isn't using the PostGreSQL JSON column type?  Only the osm2pgsql author(s) can answer that.

Comment: Yes osm2pgsql doesn't provide the data in JSON format. I wonder why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a "near to JSON" old format used by `osm2psql`... You can use with some "rarely used tags" (as [this wiki considerations](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#hstore)), that `osm2pgsql` converts to [`hstore`, and you can convert to JSON using `hstore_to_json` in PostgreSQL 9.5](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/hstore.html).

To other and more relevant data, you cited "tags column"... As defined by the  [Osm2pgsql/schema](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema),

- planet_osm_nodes.tags
- planet_osm_rels.tags
- planet_osm_ways.tags

They are `text[]` datatype (array of strings) representing "tags and values", in the format: *{tag1, value1, tag2, value2, ...}*... So, the format that  [`json_object()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) converts into JSON (or `jsonb_object` into JSONB).

---

### NOTES

Why it isn't using the PostGreSQL *JSON(B)* column type? I am not the osm2pgsql author, but is easy to understand author's decisions.

The software `osm2pgsql` is a project from the 2006's, a [time of the PostregSQL 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Release_history)... Se the [time-line of the `osm2pgsql` development](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/graphs/contributors).

A precarious *JSON* support arrives in *PostgreSQL v9.2* (2012-09), and completed as a real and professional support now (!) in 2016 with *PostgreSQL v9.5* and [*JSONB*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html) internal format.

Thus, we see the basic causes:

1. Good and reliable open source software (as PostgreSQL and osm2psql) need time, have slow evolution.
2. Professional JSON is "new" for the PostgreSQL community.

---

I am also interested in OSM JSON-modeled, but it is not so simple, is a new data-model... So, let's wayt and check what [the developpers answer here](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/533).